# All content after tags are cut off in POST request

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, post

I have a webpage that includes a button that runs a script when clicked.  The script is supposed to submit the content of two text input fields, and submit the `innerHTML` of a `<div>` with the `contenteditable` attribute set to `true`.  The problem is, if someone emboldens text and then switches to a normal typeface after typing a few words, the content submitted includes everything **before** the closing `</b>` tag.  I figured this out by echoing `$_POST` in the script that is being called.  How can I pass all content along to the script?

EDIT: My HTML is:

```
<p>Contents:</p><br/>
<div contenteditable="true" style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px; background-color:#FFFFFF" id="contents"><br/></div>
<button onclick="submit_form();">Submit</button>
```

And my Javascript is:

```
function submit_form()
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "/path/to/script.php", false);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send("file=<?php echo $_GET['file']?>" + "&x=" + document.getElementById("x").value + "&y=" + document.getElementById("y").value + "&contents=" +  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this in http://jsfiddle.net/arQT2/ (with the correct div id) and looking in my console tells me it's posting the complete contents. When you echo $_POST how are you doing that and how exactly are you viewing  its contents?

Comment: @popnoodles I have no idea as to how it did not post the complete contents.  It suddenly works fine now.  Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply call a javascript function to get rid of the tags while submitting:

```
function cleanText(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/\<[^\>]*>/g, '');
}
```

or in case you need to pass the tags too:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Comment: I actually need the tags to be submitted, and not as HTML entities.  The reason I use a `contenteditable` div is so users of the website could see how their post will be formatted.

Comment: Then convert them back when you receive them.